# CentOS 6 Unable To Install Audacious

Tags: centos, centos-6

I cannot seem to install Audacious or nearly any other program for that matter.
I think the problem is with repository priorities? I Installed the priority plugin and set some values for repos but to no avail...

Here's the message I'm getting:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                            |  17 kB     00:00     
 * base: centos.syn.co.il
 * epel: ftp.nluug.nl
 * extras: centos.syn.co.il
 * rpmforge: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
 * updates: centos.syn.co.il
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
epel                                                     | 4.3 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                          | 4.1 MB     00:07     
extras                                                   | 3.5 kB     00:00     
rpmforge                                                 | 1.1 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.5 kB     00:00     
1124 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package audacious.x86_64 0:1.4.6-1.el6.rf will be installed
-    -> Processing Dependency: audacious-plugins >= 1.4.5 for package: audacious-1.4.6-1.el6.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmcs.so.1()(64bit) for package: audacious-1.4.6-1.el6.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaudclient.so.1()(64bit) for package: audacious-1.4.6-1.el6.rf.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package audacious.x86_64 0:1.4.6-1.el6.rf will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: audacious-plugins >= 1.4.5 for package: audacious-1.4.6-1.el6.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaudclient.so.1()(64bit) for package: audacious-1.4.6-1.el6.rf.x86_64
---> Package libmcs.x86_64 0:0.7.1-1.el6.rf will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: audacious-1.4.6-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libaudclient.so.1()(64bit)
           Available: audacious-libs-1.4.6-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               libaudclient.so.1()(64bit)
           Installed: audacious-libs-2.4.5-1.el6.x86_64 (@/audacious-libs-2.4.5-1.el6.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: audacious-1.4.6-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: audacious-plugins >= 1.4.5
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need MP3 support on your CentOS 6 then try [Fluendo](http://www.fluendo.com/shop/product/fluendo-mp3-decoder/), which is free and works well.

Answer (score 1):

```
audacious-2.2-16.fc13.src.rpm
audacious-plugins-2.2-32.fc13.src.rpm
audacious-plugins-freeworld-2.2-3.fc13.src.rpm
```

Do a rebuild:

```
libmowgli-1.0.0-2.fc17.src.rpm　　　　
audacious-plugins-jack-2.2-32.el6 
audacious-plugins-esd-2.2-32.el6 
audacious-plugins-amidi-2.2-32.el6 
audacious-plugins-sid-2.2-32.el6 
audacious-plugins-wavpack-2.2-32.el6
audacious-plugins-vortex-2.2-32.el6
audacious-plugins-debuginfo-2.2-32.el6 
audacious-plugins-2.2-32.el6 
audacious-devel-2.2-16.el6
audacious-2.2-16.el6
audacious-plugins-2.2-2
audacious-libs-2.2-16.el6
libmowgli-devel-1.0.0-2.el6 
libmowgli-1.0.0-2.el6
bluez-libs-devel-4.66-1.el6
```